# Combining multiple unequal arrays by matching the keys and get the values of the matched keys

Tags: php, arrays

i want to combine 6 indexed array by matching them by keys then insert the value into my tables how can i do it?

```
[typeSex] => Array
    (
        [0] => broiler
        [1] => layer
    )    

[noheads] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 321
    )    

[origin] => Array
    (
        [0] => asd
        [1] => sda
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
    )    

[live] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 222
    )    

[carcass] => Array
    (
        [0] => 312
        [1] => 341
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
    )

[totalcarcass] => Array
    (
        [0] => 231
        [1] => 321
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
    )
```

i can combine only two arrays
here's the code that i got in another question

```
$typeSex = //the typeSex array;   
$noheads = //the noheads array;
$temp_array = array();
foreach($typeSex as $k => $v){
    if(array_key_exists($k, $noheads)){
        $temp_array[$k] = array($v, $noheads[$k]);
    }
}
```

please help me with this, thanks.

Comment: can you put your desired array output?

Comment: Show us the original array and the desired result

Comment: @Cedie here's my desired array output Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => broiler
            [1] => 123
            [3] => asd
            [4] => 123
            [5] => 222
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => layer
            [1] => 321
            [3] => sda
            [4] => 231
            [5]  => 321
        )

)

Comment: all 0 keys is the data of the broiler and all the 1 keys is the data of layer, i want to group them by their keys $temp_array is Multidimensional array containing the grouped data.

Comment: @p3ac3 sorry for the delayed answer, check mine if you still looking for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, is your desired output is?:

```
array[
      [typeSex=>'broiler', noheads=>123, origin=>'asd', live=>123, carcass=>312, totalcarcass=>231],
      [typeSex=>'layer', noheads=>321, origin=>'sda', live=>222, carcass=>341, totalcarcass=>321],
      [typeSex=>null, noheads=>null, origin=>null, live=>null, carcass=>null, totalcarcass=>null],
      [typeSex=>null, noheads=>null, origin=>null, live=>null, carcass=>null, totalcarcass=>null],
]
```

If yes, then this might be the answer:

```
        $number_of_items = [];
        $result = [];
        //get the number of items in every array and put it in an array
        array_push($number_of_items, count($typeSex), count($noheads), count($origin), count($live), count($carcass), count($totalcarcass));

        //get the largest number of items
        $max = max($number_of_items);

        //add the result variable $result
        for($i=0; $i < $max; $i++){
            array_push($result, array(
                 "typeSex" => isset($typeSex[$i])? $typeSex[$i] : null,
                 "noheads" => isset($noheads[$i])? $noheads[$i] : null,
                 "origin" => isset($origin[$i])? $origin[$i] : null,
                 "live" => isset($live[$i])? $live[$i] : null,
                 "carcass" => isset($carcass[$i])? $carcass[$i] : null,
                 "totalcarcass" => isset($totalcarcass[$i])? $totalcarcass[$i] : null,
            ));
        }
```

Comment: I mean mark it as answer so anyone with same problem can see that it solves your problem

Comment: ohh sorry just new in stackoverflow if i have 15 reputation i will vote it up too thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$arr_temp = array();
foreach($your_array as $key=>$arr)
{ 
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    { 
       if($v!="")
       {
            $arr_temp[$k][] = $v;     
       }
    }    
}

print_r($arr_temp);
```

Comment: i want to combine the 6 indexed array by key. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is it you needed.

```
$typeSex = array("typeSex" => array("broiler", "layer"));
$noheads = array("noheads" => array(123,321));
$origin  = array("origin" => array("asd","sda","",""));
$live    = array("live" => array(123,222));
$carcass =array("carcass" =>  array(312,341,'',''));
$totalcarcass = array("totalcarcass" => array(231,321));

$final = array_merge($typeSex, $noheads, $origin, $live, $carcass, $totalcarcass);


foreach ($final as $key=>$val)
{

        $res[] = $val[0];
        $ab[] = $val[1]; 
}

$aa = array($res,$ab);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($aa);
```